# tf-pose-estimation dosen't show matplotlib guest: CentOS host: windows10

Tags: visual-studio, matplotlib, windows-10, centos7, openpose

windows 10
centos 7
python 3.6.5
VScode

I'm trying OpenPose, finally I commanded this code

[vagrant@localhost tf-pose-estimation]$ python3 run.py --model=mobilenet_thin --resize=432x368 --image=images/p2.jpg

but this doesn't show any windows by matplotlib

I changed backend code

\home\vagrant.local\lib\python3.6\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl-data\matplotlibrc

backend      : Agg    =>   backend      : TKAgg

[vagrant@localhost tf-pose-estimation]$ python3 run.py --model=mobilenet_thin --resize=432x368 --image=images/p2.jpg

/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:516: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) 
or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:517: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) 
or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:518: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1)

---except parts of scripts------

TfPoseEstimator/Openpose/MConv_Stage6_L2_5_pointwise/BatchNorm/FusedBatchNorm
TfPoseEstimator/Openpose/concat_stage7/axis
TfPoseEstimator/Openpose/concat_stage7
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/vagrant/tf-pose-estimation/tf_pose/estimator.py:341: The name tf.placeholder is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.placeholder instead.

2019-09-10 12:57:56,417 WARNING From /home/vagrant/tf-pose-estimation/tf_pose/estimator.py:341: The name tf.placeholder is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.placeholder instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/vagrant/tf-pose-estimation/tf_pose/estimator.py:342: The name tf.image.resize_area is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.image.resize_area instead.

2019-09-10 12:57:56,420 WARNING From /home/vagrant/tf-pose-estimation/tf_pose/estimator.py:342: The name tf.image.resize_area is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.image.resize_area instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/vagrant/tf-pose-estimation/tf_pose/tensblur/smoother.py:96: The name tf.variable_scope is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.variable_scope instead.

2019-09-10 12:57:56,442 WARNING From /home/vagrant/tf-pose-estimation/tf_pose/tensblur/smoother.py:96: The name tf.variable_scope is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.variable_scope instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/vagrant/tf-pose-estimation/tf_pose/estimator.py:354: add_dispatch_support..wrapper (from tensorflow.python.ops.array_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.where in 2.0, which has the same broadcast rule as np.where
2019-09-10 12:57:56,463 WARNING From /home/vagrant/tf-pose-estimation/tf_pose/estimator.py:354: add_dispatch_support..wrapper (from tensorflow.python.ops.array_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.where in 2.0, which has the same broadcast rule as np.where
2019-09-10 12:57:56.563567: W tensorflow/compiler/jit/mark_for_compilation_pass.cc:1412] (One-time warning): Not using XLA:CPU for cluster because envvar TF_XLA_FLAGS=--tf_xla_cpu_global_jit was not set.  If you want XLA:CPU, either set that envvar, 
or use experimental_jit_scope to enable XLA:CPU.  To confirm that XLA is active, pass --vmodule=xla_compilation_cache=1 (as a proper command-line flag, not via TF_XLA_FLAGS) or set the envvar XLA_FLAGS=--xla_hlo_profile.
2019-09-10 12:57:57.584627: W tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:107] Allocation of 24164352 exceeds 10% of system memory.
[2019-09-10 12:58:04,331] [TfPoseEstimatorRun] [INFO] inference image: images/p2.jpg in 1.3923 seconds.
2019-09-10 12:58:04,331 INFO inference image: images/p2.jpg in 1.3923 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.
Vbox just not on GUI.
Thanks watching.

This teached me how to install GUI on centos7
https://zero-config.com/centos/gnome-0001.html